# Using sed to add multiple lines of variables in beginning of file

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to write 3 lines at the beginning of my file using sed. I've decided to assign these to variables because they're pretty long texts and it would be easier to read.

I'm trying to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wo-national-phase-information SYSTEM "wo-national-phase-information-v1-5.dtd">
<wo-national-phase-information country='US' file-name='US-IB-FEB-2019.xml'>
```

I've assigned each one to: 
SED_HELPER_ONE
SED_HELPER_TWO
SED_HELPER_THREE

respectively. Also, is it possible to use variables in the sed command?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't even use `sed` for this. Instead, use `cat`

```
cat - foo.xml > tmp <<EOF && mv tmp foo.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wo-national-phase-information SYSTEM "wo-national-phase-information-v1-5.dtd">
<wo-national-phase-information country='US' file-name='US-IB-FEB-2019.xml'>
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on sed:

```
v1='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
v2='<!DOCTYPE wo-national-phase-information SYSTEM "wo-national-phase-information-v1-5.dtd">'
v3="<wo-national-phase-information country='US' file-name='US-IB-FEB-2019.xml'>"

sed "1i\\
$v1\\
$v2\\
$v3" file
```

If it works as you want, add the `-i` option to save in-place.